# How to rewrite specific urls from using mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have different languages' sites like mydomain/en/mobile, mydomain/de/mobile etc. New mobile websites are coming and the url has changed from f.x. /en/mobile to /mobile/en etc., so i want to redirect first few pages, and later all to new link. I have such rule implemented for single language and it works :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/mobile/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/mobile/en [L,R=301]
```

Now i need two rules - one which redirect all languages and one which redirects just few of them - f.x. en/de/fr should be redirected but others shouldn't be.

Comment: So match `(en|de|fr)` then ... FYI, you don’t need to use a RewriteCond if you are only checking on the path component of the URL, you can do the matching in the RewriteRule pattern.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on right path.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```
RewriteRule ^/(en|de|fr)/mobile(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/mobile/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You sure? When you configure rewriting in .htaccess context, the leading slash of the path has been stripped off at that point already, so `^/` should never match anything. I’d expect this to work only when you make that `^(en|de|fr)/...`